# Where is the best place to start taking over the world?

Tags: warfare, politics, geography

You finally have it. Technology, decades ahead of the rest of the world, that if scaled up will allow you to conquer the entire planet, to finally achieve your dream of bringing peace and mandatory cat ownership to mankind.

You have a modest endowment of a few billion USD thanks to the obscenely profitable legitimate cat food business you ran as a cover (you are a genius, after all, just bent on world domination).

What you need to do now is set up an initial base of operations. Completing this first step is needed to allow you to set up your (fusion-powered) droid and drone factories.

**Where is the best place on Earth to get started and, more importantly, why?**

Comment: Given human history and human nature, I'd be inclined to say there would only be world peace if there was only one human. Based on that, is your advanced technology thermonuclear weapons you're willing to use?

Comment: Oh I support your global domination goals, especially the mandatory cat ownership!

Comment: [Rather related](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/concealing-my-earth-changing-invention), but for different purposes, obviously! *shifty eyes*

Comment: @Frostfyre: That human, being alone, would commit suicide...

Comment: Related: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23350/could-an-average-person-take-over-the-world/ (that one's just for Average Joe... no billions of dollars of cat food profits)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a very old question getting modern answers yet violates the modern rules (too story-based, opinion-based, needs details, not about worldbuilding... take your pick).

Comment: “Do what you can, with what you have, where you are.” —Theodore Roosevelt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everywhere..and nowhere.

Even with the most lethal weapons controlling the world would be quite difficult.  Look at the US invasion of Iraq.  Compared to the weapons Iraq had the US had an overwhelming weapon superiority, in numbers, quality, and technology.  They still ended up leaving Iraq without any real success.  Why, because destroying a nations defenses are not the same as controlling the people.

To control the people you need effectively boots on the ground, intelligent people right there to control the area your in.  A giant super-bomber or orbital death ray is great at blowing up big military weapons, but it does little to keep people from refusing to pay taxes, or rioting, or gurella warfare with simple weapons that are no threat to orbital death rays, but still lead your infantry to be afraid of leaving their barracks.

Unless your willing to do a full on terror mode, where you make everyone too terrified of you to do anything else by killing anyone that does anything at all to upset you your find the people resisting your rule vehemently long long after your super-weapons have destroyed all major weapons of war.  Even if you go full on totalitarian your going to need a very loyal defensive guard to protect against assassins, and spend your life trapped in a bunker for fear that if you go outside so many people hating you means multiple attempts on your life.

This is assuming you have advanced but not 'god-mode' level technology.  If your have controllable mass-produced strong AI, smart nanotech, or big-brother level of spying power you may be better off, but if you have such game breaking power you can pretty much rule from anywhere.

In short, military conquest of the world is not going to be a good idea.  Your make a world where everyone resits you, assassins are everywhere, and either no work get's done, or work only gets done because you are the most evil of totalitarian governor everywhere that make people work via constant fear of death.

Of course there is another option, you could just take over the world economically.  You have technology worlds beyond what everyone else has after all.  Sell it!  First create some black box, so others can't produce whatever it is you sell, then set up a perfect monopoly on technology everyone wants.

In the most benign scenario you become what legends like steve jobs and bill gates are/were, only three times as much.  You have so much money you don't know what to do with it, everyone respects your genius, you can play on the big stage, and you don't really need to do anything but enjoy the easy life.

If you really *must* control the governments, not just enjoy being the richest and most important person in the world, then you can always use your monopoly to control them.  If the government doesn't go along with what you demand your instant-food-replicators will no longer be provided to that nation, and they can go back to having their population starve while everyone eats all the free easy food you are providing.  Your super-computer come with backdoors that you can use to shut them off if someone doesn't cooperate; killing their economy etc.  Once your technology is mandatory you have massive control to dictate terms  to those who want it.

If you do this politely and subtly enough people won't realize how much power you have, or if they do at least won't hate you enough to want to resist you because of it (again, look at the monopolies currently, Microsoft and apple have both had some practices we didn't like as consumers, both have tried to force their monopolies on the world through shade methods; but ultimately they provided the best products and we still used them even if we complained about their practices).

This seems a better way to control more of the world, with you leading a much easier life and a higher chance of actually working, and as a minor added bonus, doesn't require a war that decimates the world population (you know, minor plus) :)

Answer (score 8):

**Everywhere** is fine, where you have pretty fast internet. Why? Well, conquering that planet in a traditional way is mostly impossible without destroying way to much stuff. So consider this:

Set up a specialized cat video web service and place sublime suggestive Orders inside. After you finished a survey about "who likes what cat videos the most", you can switch your suggestions from general friendliness to specific actions, especially "adopt a company selected cat for your home". With your financial reserves, you could easily set up homeless animal shelters *everywhere*, and now your suggestive videos suggest all humans to venture to your shelters and adopt one (may work with dogs too).

These cats than have been bred to pass a special affinity to you food only to all childs. And they are kind of... fertile too. And they are trained superior in charming themselves into the hearts of all humans nearby. Now wait some cat-generations an suddenly you have a world full of people that own a cat of your bidding, which carve on your food and know how to look half-starving if they do not get a constant supply of your food.

And of course you can always fall back to implementing enhanced harmony distribution devices into the cats to make people more friendly in general... you could modulate the purring by unharmful genetics engineering to be even more relaxing for a start. or make cat-poop send out pheromones that trigger happiness-hormone-production in the humans disposing it. Wait, that could backfire.

And suddenly you can press whole countries to your bidding, just by shortening the supply of your cat-food, if they do warlike stuff. Every warmonger would consider his actions, if his beloved fur-ball start looking sad. I would say, this makes you effectively to the worlds most powerful person.

Goal reached.

Comment: This is hilarious, but it could work. That is, except for the happiness-hormone-production :)

Answer (score 4):

In the United States, some place where a couple hundred million can swing the state elections.

- Sooner or later, you have to face the US. Do it from inside rather than from outside.
- Meanwhile, the political and military power of the United States will defend your operations against outside interference. If you build the fusion power plant in some third world country, the US would be really suspicious.
- Any premature sightings of your drones will be blamed on Area 51.
- Reasonably decent infrastructure.

Comment: +1. Also, when becomming the President of the USA, you can command the Area 51 to produce you some neat Evil Overlord technologies

Answer (score 1):

Starting in France is crucial, France is a extremely strategic spot thanks to the alps and the Pyrenees cutting off France from Spain and Italy. Sea blocks France from Britain and a small mountain range cuts off France from Germany, however the mountain range that   protects France from Germany has a small gap in the northern area giving free access to France you protect that area and fortify it, you've got a great area to start world domination. Another reason to start in France is the Mediterranean sea a great spot to create a trading empire.
After France I would take Germany, Italy, and Spain, each having strategical benefits. Italy has the alps to the north and is surrounded by sea if France ever falls to the enemy, you can use Italy as a backup while you regain control over France it is also useful for fishing. Spain is alright it´s best benefit is the strait of Gibraltar. You can use that and the area below the strait to gain control of trading through-out the Mediterranean, doing this can help strengthen your own empire and weaken the country´s within the Mediterranean. Germany is very good for farming it rains a lot and is covered with valleys and lowland. Use this to feed your empire.
Next take Greece, the area around Greece is covered with water and islands great for fishing, you can also use Greece to control the black sea, use the black sea to penetrate deeper within the Asian continent, the Ukraine is also good for farming, use this to keep up with the growing concerns for food. By now you have most of the European continent by now do whatever you want, I would recommend taking control over the Baltic sea. Using the Mediterranean control the Seas! and make allies with many of the countries you plan to take over last, like japan, the USA and china make sure to treat the land to take over kindly and let them remain sovereign to a point if they make a move to rise up. crush them under your boot and make a example to anyone else thinking of rising up. Have fun taking over the world with you cat empire!:)

Comment: But cats and cocks don't fit well together .... :-)